# Are there performance benefits to creating a Hashmap with defined types vs. Objects?

Tags: java, casting, hashmap

When should I do one, and when should I do the other, especially in cases where both suffice? For example, consider if I need a Hashmap of type `<String, String>`. Is there any reason to do a hashmap of type `<Object, Object>`?

Are there performance benefits/penalties for either, or is it an issue of clarity?

Comment: Generics is your friend. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Your question is valid only till `java-1.4`. From `java-1.5` generics will do the trick

Comment: BTW You can only store a reference to an object in the HashMap, you don't store/copy the actual object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you are using HashMap like this:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("aKey","value");
String v =(String)map.get("aKey");
```

You can use it like this:

```
Map<String,String> map= new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("aKey","value");
String v = map.get("aKey");
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it is used as a polymorphic reference. You want String I may want my own custom Class. So make it generic they have used Objects. However you can use generics to avoid cast.

Comment: Thanks! I don't fully understand generics (except in a sort of superficial sense) so this is all a little fuzzy to me.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you initialize it. According to the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), the `HashMap` can take the data types of what it is storing, so if you do this:

```
Map hashMap = new HashMap();
map.put("hello", "abc");
```

You would need to cast to get back your keys and data. However, if you do something like so:

```
Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
map.put("hello", "abc");
```

You no longer need to cast the objects that you have. You can take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) for more information on Generics.

Answer (score 1):

```
            //If you dont make generic then you have to cast the object
            HashMap myMap = new HashMap();

            // If you make it generic then you dont have to cas the object
            HashMap<String, String> myMap2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. An additional clarification is that .... objects are never stored inside a HashMap. Instead the reference/identity of the object is kept inside.
2. On retrieval, actual reference is picked from the location (given by HashMap) and provided to caller.
3. Purpose of Java generics is to apply compile time checks only; it has noting to do with run-time.
4. What if reference points to an Integer and type-cast is expecting a String?
5. Generics simplify the programming and helps in avoiding Class Cast errors at run-time.